# Print subreport total to main report header

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, subreport

I have a report with sub report.
I'm able to print sub report total to main reports footer.
But i need to print sub reports total to main reports header.

### Sub report footer formula

```
//@SubCrSum
//Stores the grand total of the {dtPanding.Credit} field
//in a number variable called 'crSubTotal'
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NUMBERVar crSubTotal := Sum ({dtPanding.Credit})
```

### Main report formula

```
//@showSubBalance
//Returns the value that was stored in the shared currency variable called
//crSubTotal in the subreport
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NUMBERVar crSubTotal;
crSubTotal
```

When i put main report formula field into footer of main report then it print sub reports footer properly.
But when i put this into header section then it prints 0.
Can any one help me in printing sub report total into report header.

Answer (score 0):

It is the behaviour of the crystal reports... to display correctly in report header you need to place the sub report before the main report header or else you can try below solution:

1. After retriving the sub report value in main report footer store it locally in a variable.
2. Now try to display that in main report header. something like below;

   `WhilePrintingRecords;
   Shared NUMBERVar crSubTotal;
   Shared Numbervar abc;
   abc:=crSubTotal`

Now create a formula in main report hearder;

```
Shared numbervar abc;
abc
```

Note: This is not tested code, Just an idea.